# DOM disabled property

Tags: html, javascript, google-chrome

I have a script which is setting a `<fieldset>`'s `disabled` attribute

```
document.getElementById(someID).disabled = true
```

but this does not work in WebKit (Chrome/Safari).  Is there a better/different way to do this, or a WebKit workaround?

Comment: What type of element are you trying to assign it on?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  I also think "someID" would need to be in quotes.

Comment: @Sparky672: In my example `someID` is a variable containing the name of the ID.  Of course if it were a literal it would be quoted.

Comment: @Charles:  That would have made perfect sense if you had included all relevant code in your question.

Comment: @Niklas: Good question.  It's a `<fieldset>`.

Comment: @Sparky672: I didn't think the 2000 LOC of script + markup would be particularly useful.  `someID` points to the ID of a `<fieldset>` tag in the document.  Internet Explorer 9 and Firefox 4.01 disable the fieldset without problems, but Chrome won't.

Comment: @Charles:  Really?  Posting 2000 lines of code is the **only** way to let us know what you want?  (See `" "` in both answers below)

Comment: @Sparky672: Without knowing what information you would have wanted, all I could have done would have been to post my complete code.  Had I thought to mention what the tag was I would have done so, but I didn't.  (That seems a much larger omission than explaining that I'm not a dunce using an unquoted string...!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fieldset.disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/fieldset) is available as of HTML5. HTML5 until now is only a working draft and therefore you should not rely on it. Do it like DanMan wrote and iterate over all `<input>` and `<textarea>` an set `node.disabled=true`.

[code.google: HTML5 Fieldset Disabled Tag Does Not Work In Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=78804)

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable a fieldset element. You'd have to loop over all the contained form elements like inputs, textareas and selects and disable them all individually.

Comment: Yes, you can (according to the [HTML standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#the-fieldset-element)).

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Right -- and it works in Firefox and even Internet Explorer.

Comment: Ok, another HTML5 feature (draft) I didn't know about. But I don't think you can rely on that yet.

Answer (score 0):

[Try](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/LPBBU/):

```
document.getElementById("someID").disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("someID").disabled = "disabled";
```